# SwipeRefreshLayout from support21 force to old style

Tags: android, android-support-library

I just updated the support library - and the new SwipeRefreshLayout is not my taste. Is there a way to get the old style back? There are still the setColor methods - which is kind of strange - they seem to have no use anmore. I really hope to have the old style I do not have to stick to the old library.

Comment: Most likely, the only way to get "the old style back" (whatever that means exactly) is to get the file(s) from the AOSP version control system and make your own fork.

Comment: the old style was a nice colorful animation not interfearing with my layout - the new one is the complete opposite - I fear to be forced to do or use a fork - but wanted to ask first - perhaps there is some trick to not have this pain

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do this as well - I needed the "Holo" SwipeRefreshLayout with the top horizontal line indicator as opposed to the pull-down-rotating-arrow indicator.

You can actually just reference an older version of the android support library in your project if you want the old SwipeRefreshLayout; e.g.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
```

I'm not sure if version 21 is old enough; you might have to go back to 20. The caveat here is of course if you need functionality from one of the newer support library versions you won't have access to that functionality.